# Increment value in TextView by pressing button

Tags: android

I want to be able to increment the value in my textview by pressing a button. I tried the code below, but when I press the button the app crashes.

**XML**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:onClick="incrementScore"
    android:text="@string/player" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="42dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:text="@string/player_score" />
```

**The button is on the main screen. Here is the incrementScore method**

```
public void incrementScore(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Increment.class);

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

**Increment class onCreate**

```
Context context;    
TextView tv;
Button incrementer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
    tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    incrementer=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    context=this;

    incrementer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            String present_value_string = tv.getText().toString();
            int present_value_int = Integer.parseInt(present_value_string);
            present_value_int++;

            tv.setText(String.valueOf(present_value_int));          
        }
    });

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}
```

**Android Manifest**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.experiment.Home"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.experiment.Increment"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_increment" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Log Cat**

```
04-25 15:32:56.664: D/libEGL(27300): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
04-25 15:32:56.674: D/libEGL(27300): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
04-25 15:32:56.674: D/libEGL(27300): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
04-25 15:32:56.694: D/OpenGLRenderer(27300): Enabling debug mode 0
04-25 15:33:01.260: D/AndroidRuntime(27300): Shutting down VM
04-25 15:33:01.260: W/dalvikvm(27300): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4112e2a0)
04-25 15:33:01.260: E/AndroidRuntime(27300): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-25 15:33:01.260: E/AndroidRuntime(27300): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.experiment/com.example.experiment.Increment}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-25 15:33:01.260: E/AndroidRuntime(27300):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2092)
04-25 15:33:01.260: E/AndroidRuntime(27300):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2117)
04-25 15:33:01.260: E/AndroidRuntime(27300):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:134)
04-25 15:33:01.260: E/AndroidRuntime(27300):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1218)
04-25 15:33:01.260: E/AndroidRuntime(27300):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-25 15:33:01.260: E/AndroidRuntime(27300):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-25 15:33:01.260: E/AndroidRuntime(27300):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
04-25 15:33:01.260: E/AndroidRuntime(27300):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-25 15:33:01.260: E/AndroidRuntime(27300):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-25 15:33:01.260: E/AndroidRuntime(27300):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
04-25 15:33:01.260: E/AndroidRuntime(27300):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
04-25 15:33:01.260: E/AndroidRuntime(27300):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-25 15:33:01.260: E/AndroidRuntime(27300): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-25 15:33:01.260: E/AndroidRuntime(27300):    at com.example.experiment.Increment.onCreate(Increment.java:29)
04-25 15:33:01.260: E/AndroidRuntime(27300):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5047)
04-25 15:33:01.260: E/AndroidRuntime(27300):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
04-25 15:33:01.260: E/AndroidRuntime(27300):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2056)
04-25 15:33:01.260: E/AndroidRuntime(27300):    ... 11 more
04-25 15:33:01.320: D/dalvikvm(27300): GC_CONCURRENT freed 181K, 10% free 9551K/10567K, paused 13ms+2ms, total 53ms
```

Please help

Comment: What is the default String value in the TextView?

Comment: please point for me line 29 of Increment.java

Comment: I set the value to zero in the res/values/strings.xml file. Is that what you meant, or is there another way to set the default value for a TextView?

Comment: add android:text="0" in your xml layout

Comment: Where precisely in the xml layout?

Comment: Hardcoding it in the TextView part of the xml still gives the same result. The app crashes as soon as I press the button.

Comment: I wonder why do you guys keep asking confusing questions not specifying the name of the layout you post and where you use it. The problem must be that the layout is set to Fragment instead of the Activity. The posted layout should be activity_home.

Comment: in onclick method(){ text.textSize(i++)};//i=ur default text size

Answer (score 0):

I'm just confused with your code man. You have posted a method

```
public void incrementScore(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Increment.class);

    startActivity(intent);
}
```

and don't know that where you are calling this and for what you are starting an activity in that method.

And in the Increment.class, you wrote code for fragment transaction(in an activity). Is it needed? Are you aware of the fragmentmanager and using it.

I think you are calling the method incrementScore() somewhere and that leads your app to crash. Can you please post the exact code you are using in detail?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `onClick = incrementScore` in the XML File